# How to set IsEnabled to always be True for ScrollBar?

Tags: .net, wpf

A `ScrollBar` will be `IsEnabled=False` whenever it is determined that there is no need to support a scrollbar. Currently, I want `ScrollBar` which will be `IsEnabled=True` whenever it is `Visible`. How to set `IsEnabled` to always be `True` for `ScrollBar`?

I use MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ScrollBar` overrides `IsEnabledCore`:

```
protected override bool IsEnabledCore
{ 
    get { return base.IsEnabledCore && _canScroll; }
}
```

That means if it can't scroll, it'll be disabled, and you can't override it by changing properties. The only way to modify this logic is to subclass `ScrollBar` and override `IsEnabledCore`:

```
public class ScrollBar_AlwaysEnabled : ScrollBar
{
    protected override bool IsEnabledCore
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

This `ScrollBar` will always respect `IsEnabled` property.

Note that this will only change scroll bar logic if you use this control explicitly. A lot of controls use scroll bars in their templates and if you want to change their behavior, you'll need to completely replace their control templates. Overall, it isn't worth it.

Comment: Thanks @Discord. maybe I will reconsider the request for my project. Because create a subclass ScrollBar isn't worth it.

Comment: @Mr.Le In all properly implemented applications, useless scroll bars are either hidden or disabled. It doesn't make any sense to leave them enabled, as it isn't what users expect and it'll be confusing.